# Export OS X Lion Blog / Wiki

Tags: server.app, macos

We have a blog on OS X Lion Server with about 750 Entries and would like to export them in order to migrate to a different platform (Confluence).

Although I found a solution to [export a Snow Leopard Blog/Wiki to CSV](http://www.jonsblog.org/2012/05/12/export-osx-wiki-server-to-csv/), I couldn't find anything to export the Blog Data of a Lion Server installation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ready-made solution for this AFAIK. This [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5082) tells how to backup and restore the whole wiki or just a single wiki (or blog?), but the output created by "wikiadmin export" seems to be some binary dump of the database which can be fed only to "wikiadmin import".

The Lion Server Blog/Wiki itself is kept in a Postgres database named "collab", which you can access from the server's command line: `sudo -u _postgres psql collab`. The table structure seems quite complex, though - I have a test wiki with 2 documents and it still has 67 tables. You might want to try some graphical frontend for Postgres 
 to look through the tables and export those needed.

Comment: Yep. Snow Leopard used a totally different system which was based on both an sqlite3 database including revisions AND actual html files. In Lion, the wiki was moved into Postgres, aside from attachments, so what Marie says is correct: much more difficult. Until someone tailor-makes an "OSX Wiki Postgres - to - something" utility, you're in for some trouble. Maybe the best bet is to find a CMS that can scrape content from a running web server, and then run it on yours.